# Send command to daemon

Tags: linux, daemon, minecraft

I have a minecraft server running as a daemon. When you run it normally (not as a daemon), you can type commands into the console. How can you get to the console so I can send it commands while it's running as a daemon?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend running something like this in a [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) session instead. The benefit of screen is that you can reattach to the console whenever you like to run a command, then send it to the background again as needed.

- First type `screen` to start a session.
- Run your minecraft server as you would in standalone mode.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.

You can now close your terminal session and minecraft or whatever software you use will continue to run in the background. Running `screen -r` will reattach you to this session to run commands.